# How to figure out exactly what will be expected at a new workplace and face it

Tags: colleagues, new-job, work-experience, new-hires, academia

I have been working at a state university as a lecturer, actually in a senior position (on contract though) because I have a post graduate qualification as well, completed with a research component.

My graduation has been a bit recently and so I have only about two years of experience in this place. At the end of the contract, I've chosen to go to another place, which is a private university this time.

Usually, in our country, the state universities are considered to offer better quality degrees, better experienced academics, even the high scoring students at high school enter those usually. Now, the people at the private place had more interest to select me to their vacant position, because I'm a person with experience in such a state university and also because of the lack of people like me who have got qualified and experienced in state universities being enrolled to work in private places like that. That's what they explained.

And they said that they are looking forward to benefit from my experience to enhance their quality of education as well. With the mentioning of this, I felt as if a quite a load has been placed on my shoulders. I'll be starting there in a few days.

What do you think about this situation?

In these type of situations, I'm concerned whether they'll expect me to guide them through a whole new world of new experiences. Or if I'm able to suggest some practices which I've seen in my previous place which are lacking here would be enough at the beginning, while I carry on with teaching as I usually do with the subjects allocated to me?

As I mentioned earlier, I also don't have that much of experience in the field still, even though I have a good insight on completing my own tasks well, I'm not sure whether I'll be able to guide a whole lot of people at this new place to give out a very high standard at once. There, I'm not sure what type of extent is expected from me with regards to benefiting from my experience, and I'm quite concerned, will it affect if I'm unable to satisfy what they need? But I still don't even know what they need exactly either.

If I make any mistakes, I'm concerned whether they'll be paying more attention to me and start criticizing/laughing more as they expect me to be more experienced. I mean, as a human I might be making mistakes too right...But it makes me feel stressed.

What type of services I can usually suggest and do to improve the quality of an educational institute like that is also another concern, where I'd be glad to have suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It seems that there are so many questions in one single post. (BTW, I did not downvote your post.)

Comment: And yet zero questions that people on the internet can answer.

Comment: Thanks @Job_September_2020 and thanks for explaining that you didn't downvote :) I've done edits to the question now

Comment: Perhaps Academia StackExchange might be more of a help with a better-phrased version of your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking us to guess at what the expectations of your new employers/coworkers are going to be, which is not something we can do. That being said, it seems as though this anxiety stems from you believing that working at a higher quality school is going to cause high expectations. I think you should relax a little bit there. Not only have you only worked 2 years at the state uni, it sounds like you only graduated 2 years ago. Your employers and your coworkers are going to be aware of this, I don't see why they would expect you to have the knowledge and expertise of someone much older than you.

Your 2 years of work at the state university will still be valuable to you and to them, so do not sell that short, but if your new job is somewhere worth working then they won't expect more than what you have to offer.

Comment: Hmm okay then @InBedded16 Thanks a lot. Usually what type of things can we do to improve the quality of education at a university? If you have suggestions of such things an individual can manage to approach and do (an individual like me), please kindly let me know that too.

Comment: @Mary - I humbly suggest that you spend the first weeks [most likely the first months] working with, and more importantly listening to your Administration & colleagues to hear what their concerns/hopes are for improving your new Uni. It is almost a certainty that they have both new and ongoing concerns, and will want to tap your experiences to help them craft policies to address them. Going in with a list of expectations/pre-conceived notions of what is required/desired may very well cloud your vision and appraisal of your new Uni, and that could impair your ability to provide good advice.

Answer (score 5):

Forget the puff about you enhancing their quality of education.  They are a lower ranked university, and they have a vacancy to fill, so they will take anyone who looks like they have the right qualification.  They want to make you feel like you haven't taken a step down the career ladder by joining them.

Nobody likes the new guy who starts a new job, then immediately tells the existing employees that they are doing things wrong.

So fit in.  Don't push any agenda.  Do what the other staff do.  Once you're established, you might look at changing things a bit.  But not too much.